# × TypeError: _questions_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.map is not a function (react)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, file

I am using React and my home.js is

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Data from "./questions.json"
class Home extends Component{

    render(){return(
        <div>


            {Data.map((questionDetail, index)=>{
                return <h1>{questionDetail.questions}</h1>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}}
export default Home
```

The Json file is

```
{
"questions":{
"question_one":"This is a question"
}}
```

If anyone knows the answer to this problem, I would be very grateful.

Comment: `.map` is a function on arrays. The json you showed does not contain an array.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON file type is not a must for you then you can rename your file extension as `js` and export array of objects as below:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        questions: {
            question_one: 'This is a question',
        },
    },
];
```

Then you can iterate on it via `map` function.